# Inconsistent variable values in Nuxt 3 components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I have a simple Vue signin/signup form.
I have prepared funny dummy data for placeholders, so every time page reloads it will be displaying a random person data in my form:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
    const isLogin = ref(true);

    const dummyData = [
        ['Euclid', 'euclid@greece.old'],
        ['Gauss', 'gauss@math.king'],
        ['Einstein', 'albert@relative.phys'],
    ];

    const cDummy = dummyData[Math.floor(Math.random()*dummyData.length)];
</script>
```

Then I use the data in `cDummy` const in template:

```html
<template>
    <label v-if="!isLogin">
        <div>Name</div>
        <input type="text" :placeholder="cDummy[0]" required>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div>Email</div>
        <input type="email" :placeholder="cDummy[1]" required>
    </label>

    <a @click="isLogin = !isLogin">{{ modeLabels.switchText }}</a>
</template>
```

The problem is when I change reactive `isLogin` variable, the newly added input `Name` field placeholder name sometimes does not fit with dummy email. For example, the mail was `gauss@math.king` and the added name is `Euclid` and so on.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Your console log will only run on startup or page refresh which may not be the same event/happen in this case - just a general DOM/JavaScript comment as I do not consider myself  an expert with vue.js or nuxt.js.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I unserstand that. But the constant value should be set only once too, just as this `console.log()`. But, for some reason, when the DOM updates it somehow manages to take the wrong name from non-reactive variable without triggering `console.log()` once again.

Comment: @LukeVo yeah but this does not explain how Vue (or Nuxt) is doing the same operation (getting random array element) twice without triggering `console.log()`. I am new to all this reactivity-stuff and I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: There's not enough code shown to actually reproduce the problem.  Are you changing `cDummy` at any point after the component is created?  If you are, the UI won't update to reflect this because it's not a reactive variable.  For that you need to use Vue's [ref or reative](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html) functions to wrap the const's initial value. If you're using Composition API with the `setup()` function the variable must also be returned from it.

Comment: It might also help to show how exactly you're updating your `isLogin` variable

Comment: @yoduh I do use Composition API and no, I do not touch `cDummy` and `dummyData` variables other than displaying values in template (`cDummy[0]` and `cDummy[1]`). My guess is than changing reactive `isLogin` bool variable triggers DOM update and adding new input and somewhere in this process, somehow, `cDummy` is changed but I honestly don't know how this is happening.

Comment: @yoduh Tried to reproduce and failed. On stackblitz minimal exapmle works just fine. It seems, there is something wrong with my code...

Comment: @CMTV Put behind your post the entire file code please.
The way we see your code is you use script setup? So in that case it's normal that the console.log is executed only once, because it's launch to setup the component and never re-run.

Comment: @RaphaelRlt updated the code.

Comment: My guess is that you're using some sort of server-side rendering and hydration. The email field, being always present, is statically rendered with the server-chosen value. The name field, being dynamically shown, is hydrated and gets a value that is randomly chosen on the client. Not the behavior I would expect, but quite possible.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I am using Nuxt 3 and yes, this could be the thing... :( I am new to this framework (and all other frameworks)

Comment: @DarrylNoakes huh, I added `!isLogin` check to `email` too and now the values are synced so it kind of proves your theory. The only thing now is to understand what to do...

Comment: The way nuxt3 is handle in development should not affect this for me.
The first things i see is you use a link balise and maybe the execute is not what you thinks.

Do you try doing this two things?
const cDummy = ref(dummyData[Math.floor(Math.random()*dummyData.length)]);
<button @click="() => isLogin = !isLogin">{{ modeLabels.switchText }}</button>

Comment: @RaphaelRlt just tried this and no, both options do not help... And I can't reproduce it on stackblitz which is even more weird...

Comment: Tried to restart the server and it showed two console.logs! So the @DarrylNoakes was right I guess. One value is computed on the server and the other is computed on client... Super weird. Now I guess I need to somehow generate this only on client side...

Comment: But you are in development environnement or on a server with your dist?

Comment: I am in dev mode on my PC...

Comment: Every time I refresh page two `console.log()` are called: one in browser for `name` input and one in server log for `email` input.

Comment: Well, this seems weird to me. I'm pretty sur it's related to your project. But maybe you render in ssr mode on local and @DarrylNoakes guess right.
I try it localy on a production project with nuxt3 script setup and ssr mode.

I do not have the problem everything works like intended.

Comment: Ok I will try to create another test project on my PC and see whether it is working on "clean" install.

Comment: Well i don't see before you comments. If you see two logs it's not intended for me. I never work with ssr in dev, only production.
So based on what you say i think you see one inside your browser(console) and one in you cmd(where you execute the dev).

It's maybe because inside your nuxt.config file you have ssr, so try to remove it in dev adding this:
```ssr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',```

Comment: @RaphaelRlt Yeah, created test project and the behaviour is the same - values are out of sync, two console logs called: one in browser, one in cmd. If I disable SSR it will not resolve my issue because this will be broken on production... One way to fix this would be to simply `useFetch` dummy data but it is inefficient... I just need to find a way to make this code portion run client-only...

Comment: I guess I need to create a new and more appropriate question with all data we now have.

Comment: @RaphaelRlt Finally fixed it by wrapping this two inputs with `<ClientOnly>` tags. Damn, I already wonder what discoveries Nuxt is planning for me next...

Comment: @RaphaelRlt I finnaly found the coolest and fastest solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxt 3 actually kind of doing rendering [twice](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#universal-rendering): one on server to generate immediate HTML and show at least something to site visitor and another one in browser to enable page interactivity.

So the server calculates its own `cDummy` value and when it comes to browser, it calculates `cDummy` once again, which can be different.

In order to fix this you need to create client-server-shared variable which can be done by using [`useState`](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/state-management).

```js
const cDummy = useState('cDummy', () => dummyData[Math.floor(Math.random()*dummyData.length)]);
```

It creates a reactive which value is then passed to client along with generated HTML and other data. Later in browser it uses already generated on server value instead of generating another one.

Also, many thanks to [@DarrylNoakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15261914/darryl-noakes) and [@RaphaelRlt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13278223/raphael-rlt) for helping me to understand what is happening!